# pthread: hybrid locking using mutex and spin lock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, spinlock

Good morning. I thought that mixing up the mutex and spin lock would speed up the locking process. So, I tried to create a hybrid lock by mixing the mutex lock and the spin lock. Below is what I thought when I wrote the code.

1. Wait for lock acquisition, spin for 1 second and wait for lock.
2. If the lock is not acquired after 1 second, block the thread.
3. The lock is given priority to the thread in the block state.

My code is as follows, and it is not working properly.

```
struct hybrid_lock {
    pthread_mutex_t m_lock;
    pthread_spinlock_t s_lock;
};

int hybrid_lock_init(struct hybrid_lock *h_lock) {
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&h_lock->m_lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("mutex_init error.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(pthread_spin_init(&h_lock->s_lock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE) != 0) {
        printf("spin_init error.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int hybrid_lock_destroy(struct hybrid_lock *h_lock) {
    if(pthread_mutex_destroy(&h_lock->m_lock) != 0) {
        printf("mutex_destroy error.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(pthread_spin_destroy(&h_lock->s_lock) != 0) {
        printf("spin_destroy error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int hybrid_lock_lock(struct hybrid_lock *h_lock) {
    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    while(!(end.tv_sec > start.tv_sec && end.tv_usec > start.tv_usec)) {
        if(pthread_spin_trylock(&h_lock->s_lock) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&h_lock->m_lock);
    return 0;
}

int hybrid_lock_unlock(struct hybrid_lock *h_lock) {
    pthread_spin_unlock(&h_lock->s_lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&h_lock->m_lock);

    return 0;
}
```

Could you possibly get an indication of the wrong part?

Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: One second?  That is forever.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work.  What is to prevent one thread getting the spinlock while another thread gets the mutex?

Comment: Check futex(2) if the target is Linux and you haven't done so yet. It's a similar idea and there are usage examples there. For the code shown, trying to unlock a non-locked mutex is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @arsv Thanks for your help!